# I have a composite key for a table. I want to join on just one column of this key. Does that column need a separate index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine I have a table with a composite primary key containing DateCode and AddressCode.
I want to join that table with another table on just AddressCode.
I know there will be a single index on DateCode combined with AddressCode, since that is the primary key.  Should I also have an index on just AddressCode in this table just for the purposes of efficient joins to other tables only using the AddressCode as a foreign key?  This is was what I would do in MySQL, though I'm not sure if Microsoft SQL Server handles this situation better automatically somehow.

Comment: no, it doesn't every reference needs an index, and a composite needs a composite

Comment: can you rephrase what you said?  do i need an extra index or not in this situation?

Comment: yes you need to add an index for the one column that you reference

Comment: that, on the other hand, is a clear sentence, thanks!

Comment: Depends how your composite PK is defined. If it is `(DateCode, AddressCode)` then that PK does not provide any ordering useful for lookups on just `AddressCode`. If it is defined as `(AddressCode, DateCode)` then the index can be used for seeking by AddressCode or to merge join on another source of rows sorted by AddressCode

Comment: Indexing is a complicated question and there are no absolute answers. You need to understand how your table is used in queries to determine what indexes you should have. In small tables or lightly loaded systems you might not see much (or any) benefit. A standard approach is to index all foreign keys. Here your FK is part of the PK so the index supporting the PK might be sufficient as already indicated.

Comment: the information about the specific ordering of the columns in the composite key is very helpful, Martin Smith, thanks!

Comment: Indexing helps specific queries. Please post the query you want to optimize. Don't add indexes just because you guess they could be useful at some point.

Answer (score 4):

After further research and experimentation, I have my own answer.  Yes, a join on a column that is part of a composite key but is not the first element of that index (that is, "most significant member") requires a separate index.  Without that index, performing a JOIN on that column requires a full scan of either the composite index or the table.

To clarify this further, if there is a composite index (such as is automatically created for a composite primary key) on three columns a, b, and c, if the index was created on a, b, c via

CREATE INDEX NewIndex ON Table(a, b, c)

then a is the most significant and c is the least. If the index was created on b, c, a, like so

CREATE INDEX NewIndex ON Table(b, c, a)

then b is the most significant.  Since the index is ordered according to this significance, finding values indexed by the most significant component of a composite index requires only a trivial amount of additional effort in comparison to finding values indexed by that column alone (that is, it’s like looking for all integers that begin with “7” in an ordered list from 1 to 1000), whereas finding values indexed on less significant components of a composite index typically requires a full index scan (that is, it’s like looking for all integers that end with “7” in an ordered list from 1 to 1000).